# Runtime Exception coming when show UIAlertController(actionsheet) iOS8

Tags: ios8, uialertcontroller

Runtime exception is coming when i show **UIAlertController(ActionSheet)** in **iOS8 Beta5+ Xcode6**.

This Bug is only happening in **iPad** Devices.

I'm getting bellow exception when using the UIAlertController.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'UIPopoverPresentationController
>   (<_UIAlertControllerActionSheetRegularPresentationController:
>   0x15794370>) should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set
>   before the presentation occurs.'
>
> My Code for display ActionSheet as follows

```
     // Cancel Button
      UIAlertAction *actionCancel = [UIAlertAction
                                               actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"IDS_LABEL_CANCEL", nil)
                                               style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                   // cancel
                                                   //action handler
                                                   [self actionHandler:nil withTag:0 withButtonIndex:0];
                                               }];

      // print button
      UIAlertAction *actionPrint = [UIAlertAction
                                                      actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"IDS_LABEL_PRINT", nil)
                                                      style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

                                                          //action handler
                                                          [self actionHandler:nil withTag:kAttachmentActionSheetTag withButtonIndex:0];         
                                             }];

    // Create action sheet
     UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                                      alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil
                                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

[alertController addAction:actionCancel];
[alertController addAction:actionPrint];

     // show aciton sheet
     [self  presentViewController:alertController animated:YES
                                 completion:nil] ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On iPad the alert will be displayed as a popover using the new [UIPopoverPresentationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/index.html), it requires that you specify an anchor point for the presentation of the popover using one of the three following properties:

- [barButtonItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPopoverPresentationController/barButtonItem)
- [sourceView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPopoverPresentationController/sourceView)
- [sourceRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPopoverPresentationController/sourceRect)

In order to specify the anchor point you will need to obtain a reference to the UIAlertController's UIPopoverPresentationController and set one of the properties as follows:

```
alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = parentView;
```

Comment: Thankyou mmcomb. You just saved me.

Comment: Don't you actually need `sourceView` AND `sourceRect` if you don't have `barButtonItem`? Discussion of `sourceRect` in the docs: "Use this property in conjunction with the sourceView property to specify the anchor location for the popover".